# mysql error: an alias was previously found

Tags: mysql

I am using these codes in mysql query

```
    select c1.date,sum(SELECT IFNULL(cx.purchase-cx.sold,0))+MAX(p.openqty) as opening,c1.purchase,c1.sold,
    sum(SELECT IFNULL(cx.purchase-cx.sold,0))+MAX(p.openqty) + c1.purchase-c1.sold as closing 
from 
    (select open_qty as openqty from stock ) p
left join
(select IFNULL(a.date,b.date) as date,SELECT IFNULL(a.qty,0) as purchase,SELECT IFNULL(b.qty,0) as sold from arrival a FULL JOIN pouring b ON a.date = b.date order by 1) c1 
on c1.purchase +p.openqty>0
left join
 (select IFNULL(a.date,b.date) as date,SELECT IFNULL(a.qty,0) as purchase,SELECT IFNULL(b.qty,0) as sold from arrival a FULL JOIN pouring b ON a.date = b.date order by 1) cx 
on c1.date>cx.date
 group by c1.date,c1.purchase,c1.sold
```

It says:

```
An alias was previously found. (near "purchase" at position 170)
An alias was previously found. (near "c1" at position 179)
An alias was previously found. (near "sold" at position 182)
An alias was previously found. (near "closing" at position 190)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'SELECT IFNULL(cx.purchase-cx.sold,0))+MAX(p.openqty)  as
> opening,c1.purchase,c1.' at line 1

Please help how to overcome?

Comment: You have the same exact subquery in there two times using the same variable names in both.  Did you try changing them?

Comment: Change `sum(SELECT IFNULL(cx.purchase-cx.sold,0))` into `(SELECT sum(cx.purchase-cx.sold)`. Get the idea?

Comment: sir I changed as: select c1.date, SELECT sum(cx.purchase-cx.sold)+MAX(p.openqty) as opening,c1.purchase,c1.sold,
  sum(SELECT IFNULL(cx.purchase-cx.sold,0))+MAX(p.openqty) + c1.purchase-c1.sold as closing 
 from 
  (select open_qty as openqty from stock ) p   but still same errors

Answer (score 0):

First, subqueries need to have their own parentheses.  Second, subqueries cannot be the argument to an aggregation function.  Third, you don't need subqueries at all.  So:

```
select c1.date,
       (COALESCE(sum(cx.purchase-cx.sold), 0) + MAX(p.openqty)
       ) as opening, c1.purchase, c1.sold,
       (COALESCE(sum(cx.purchase-cx.sold), 0) + MAX(p.openqty) + c1.purchase - c1.sold
       ) as closing
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 0)) + MAX(p.openqty) + c1.purchase - c1.sold
       ) as closing     from 
        (se' at line 4

Comment: Now here is second portion
) as closing 
from 
    (select open_qty as openqty from stock ) p
left join
(select IFNULL(a.date,b.date) as date,SELECT IFNULL(a.qty,0) as purchase,SELECT IFNULL(b.qty,0) as sold from arrival a FULL JOIN pouring b ON a.date = b.date order by 1) c1 
on c1.purchase +p.openqty>0
left join
 (select IFNULL(a.date,b.date) as date,SELECT IFNULL(a.qty,0) as purchase,SELECT IFNULL(b.qty,0) as sold from arrival a FULL JOIN pouring b ON a.date = b.date order by 1) cx 
on c1.date>cx.date
 group by c1.date,c1.purchase,c1.sold

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT IFNULL(a.qty,0) as purchase,SELECT IFNULL(b.qty,0) as sold from arrival a' at line 9

Comment: @user3003813 . . . Given that my answer doesn't use `IFNULL()`, it is entirely unclear how this could generate that error.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility

```
select c1.date,sum(coalesce(cx.purchase-cx.sold,0))+MAX(p.openqty)  as opening,
c1.purchase,
c1.sold,
sum(coalesce(cx.purchase-cx.sold,0)) + MAX(p.openqty) + c1.purchase-c1.sold as closing 
from ( select open_qty as openqty from stock ) p
left join ( select coalesce(a.date,b.date) as date,
            coalesce(a.qty,0) as purchase,
            coalesce(b.qty,0) as sold 
            from arrival a 
            LEFT JOIN pouring b ON a.date = b.date 
            UNION select coalesce(a.date,b.date) as date,
            coalesce(a.qty,0) as purchase,
            coalesce(b.qty,0) as sold 
            from arrival a 
            RIGHT JOIN pouring b ON a.date = b.date 
            order by 1) c1 on c1.purchase +p.openqty>0
left join ( select coalesce(a.date,b.date) as date,
            coalesce(a.qty,0) as purchase,
            coalesce(b.qty,0) as sold 
            from arrival a 
            LEFT JOIN pouring b ON a.date = b.date 
            UNION select coalesce(a.date,b.date) as date,
            coalesce(a.qty,0) as purchase,
            coalesce(b.qty,0) as sold 
            from arrival a 
            RIGHT JOIN pouring b ON a.date = b.date order by 1) cx on c1.date>cx.date
group by c1.date,c1.purchase,c1.sold 
order by 1
```